# C# binary to string

Tags: c#, binary

I am converting integer number to binary and put it in a header of a data message.
For instance the first meesage that arrived, I would convert the counter to binary that take 4 bytes and had the data message, which is a reguler message containning a, b, c etc'.

Here is how I convert the counter :

```
//This is preparing the counter as binaryint 
nCtrIn = ...;
int nCtrInNetwork = System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(nCtrIn);
byte[] ArraybyteFormat = BitConverter.GetBytes(nCtrInNetwork);
```

Now the problem is that now in to take a nother string copy the byteFormat to the beginning of a string and in addition to add the string data.

I do that because I want only in the end to write to the file using binary writer

```
m_brWriter.Write(ArraybyteFormat);
m_brWriter.Flush();
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand this question, and I still can't. Maybe I'm groggy or something, but I believe the grammar can (and should) be improved.

Comment: And why don't you just use m_brWriter.Write(myString) after m_brWriter.Write(byteFormat)?

Comment: As mentioned I need first of all the convert from binary to a string and add the origional string to it and only than to write it to the file

Comment: Roman, you are contrradicting yourself now. Do you want to convert the int to a string or to binary (byte[]) ?

Comment: I am converting it to binary, which need to be intered as a binary to a string.

Answer (score 1):

If it's important to write to the stream in single call you can concatenate the arrays:

```
var intArray = new byte[4];       // In real code assign
var stringArray = new byte[12];   // actual arrays

var concatenated = new byte[16];
intArray.CopyTo(concatenated, 0);
stringArray.CopyTo(concatenated, 4);

m_brWriter.Write(concatenated);
m_brWriter.Flush();
```

Did you consider writing the arrays in two calls to Write?

Comment: "must write in one call" : Why? It is the nature of streams that that doesn't matter. A Stream will buffer and fragment as necessary.

Comment: I must write in one call, becaue I take in a big buffer a lot ofmessages and then flush them. I know that I can write a few timesan then flush once, But the system is built so I am not allow doing that, it will break the design of the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify by letting the BinaryWriter directly write the int - no need to conver to `byte[]` first.

The other problem is writing the message, it can be done like:

```
m_brWriter.Write(nCounterIn); 
string msg = ....; // get it as 1 big string
byte[] textData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
m_brWriter.Write(textData);
```

Or, even easier and also easier to read back:

```
m_brWriter.Write(nCounterIn); 
m_brWriter.Write(msg);
```

But note that the BinaryWriter will now put it's own lentgh-prefix in front of the string.

Comment: Good answer but with one caveat from me - it assumes the same endianess in the output file. Nitpicking I know but in games I often have to serialize out into big-endian.

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem, I didn't understand it so much

Comment: Roma, look at the code. A BinaryWriter will use it's own BitConverter, so you can write _nCounterIn_ directly. And then worry about writing a __string__ to binary.

Comment: But you can also Edit your question, or even post a new one, describing what you _Want_, and ask _How_ to do it. This question starts halfway your own solution.